# Rails: Jquery template not creating hash for background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in a Rails 4 slim file using a jquery template which uses inline css to add a background from a png sprite. Here's the code:

`style='background:url("${img_file}") ${dtmf_img_position} no-repeat; background-size:${img_size}'`

Everything looks fine but the problem is that when I look at this filename in the network tab when my browser makes the request, it shows that the filename does not have an attached hash. All the other filenames in my application are hashed correctly so I'm not sure if it has to do with the way I'm adding the background. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [asset_data_uri](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sstephenson/sprockets/Sprockets%2FContext:asset_data_uri).

```
style='background:url("${asset_data_uri(img_file)}") ${dtmf_img_position} no-repeat; background-size:${img_size}'
```